# Submitting a form using POST by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to submit a form using POST by clicking a link, and sending some hidden values.

The code I'm using is:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('a#campoA').click(function() {
  $.post('testForm2.php', { campoA: 'Submit' });
 });
});
```

```html
<form action='testForm2.php' method='post' id='testForm'>
 <input type='hidden' name='campoPrueba' value='prueba'>
 <a href='#' id='campoA'>Submit</a>
 <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

I'd like to submit the form by clicking the Submit link, but something it's not working. The testForm2.php is not opened in the browser, however, by using the 'Inspect Element' option in the browser, I can see that the testForm2.php page is requested, but not opened:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mer37.png)

You can see that the hidden field is sent through the form submit, but the target page is not being opened.

How can I open the new page (testForm2.php) on the browser after submitting the form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TusharGupta, those are already there

Comment: OP: You are submitting your form via AJAX. That is what you want? There is no code that will open in a new page.

Comment: What is the point of this? In essence a button and a link are the same. If it is just a visual thing, you can make a submit button look and feel like a link. Could you give some context?

Comment: @Dbugger, I want to show a table with a list of items, and I'd insert a link in every item that links to another page to show information about the item, but I don't want to use GET (it would be much easier using GET), as I wouldn't like that the URL shows any clues about the new page to be opened.

Comment: But why do you want to use a link, and not the submit button?

Comment: Currently I'm using a radio button to select every item from the list, and a submit button, but I'd like to submit the form using only a single click (not selecting the radio button and then clicking the button). I know it would be easy to create links and open the new page use GET (passing parameters on the url), but I'd like to hide details about the target page (that's why I want to use POST to pass and hide parameters). Thanks.

Comment: That is no reason to use links. If you want to have a link for each row, just have a <form> for each row.

Comment: I had not thought about that posibility :-o Thanks @Dbugger, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the point of this, since a **submit button** and a **link** are essentially the rest, and you can make any button look like a link through CSS. In any case...

Wouldn't this be simpler?

```
$('a#campoA').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#testform").submit();
});
```

Just prevent the default behavior of clicking a button, and afterwards, submit the form.

**Again**, if I were you, I would just make the submit button look like a link:

```
input[type=submit]{
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax doesn't open the urls you're requesting, it only retrieves data from them. If you want to see the data you're getting after your submission, you'd do something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a#campoA').click(function() {
        $.post('testForm2.php', { campoA: 'Submit' },function(data) {
              $("#result").html(data);             
        });
    });
});
```

That would show whatever was returned from testForm2.php on the div with the id "result".

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you want to just submit like a normal submit button, use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a#campoA').click(function(e) {
        $("#testForm").submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```